# Completely stripped screw removal

Tags: screws

I tried replaced one of the screws in a door frame and it completely stripped during installation and now its stuck. I have tried using a regular drill bit, extraction bit, duck tape, a hammer (to pull out), screw grab (liquid), and plyers trying to remove this thing and nothing has worked so far. How can I remove this screw, ideally without taking the door off?

I have been using google and YouTube for ideas and I'm at the point where I am seeing the same methods over and over again

Thanks

Comment: How about a picture of the problem.

Comment: Usually if at first a hammer does not work, you need a bigger hammer or a three foot ply bar, if you can get under the screw head.  If the head is gone, then use a nail punch to drive it further in, then use the tooth picks/wood dowel with glue to make a new hole.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: vice grips work a charm if you can get purchase on the screw

Comment: Hole saw around the screw, and pull it all out?